# Single Language Magento Store - Multi Language Wordpress Blog

Tags: wordpress, magento, magento-1.7, multilingual, fishpig

I've developed a single language Magento Webstore (CE 1.7.0.2) and would like to add a multi language Wordpress Blog to it. It's important that the Wordpress Environment keeps  having the same look and feel as the Magento Webstore.

I've attempted to do this by adding the Fishpig Extension to Magento and added the Polylang (http://polylang.wordpress.com/) plugin to Wordpress. If I open the WP environment without the Magento Look & Feel I do see the dropdown where I can switch from language A to B. However if I include the Magento Look & Feel this option disappears.

I spoke with the developer of Fishpig's Multisite extension, this extension doesn't offer the solution I'm looking for either.

Who knows a solution for this?

Comment: buddy get a developer working on this, i don't think anybody can answer this here... comment if you need help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Polylang plugin is not currently supported but may be in the future.

There are a few hack-ish solutions to this, however, my first question would be: for what reason do you have a single language Magento installation (single store) and then want a multi-lingual blog?

The easiest solution would be to create a different store view for each language you have and then, using WordPress Multisite, assign a different blog to each store view. This would give you as many different languages as you need.

The only issue I can see with this would be that when you're viewing a post, if you change store view, you won't be taken to the equivalent post on the new store view as the URLs would not match due to the language differences. To fix this, you could add a RewriteRule to your htaccess file that always redirects to the blog homepage when you're changing store while viewing the blog.

If you have to use a single Magento store and still want a multi-lingual blog, it would be possible using the [Root](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/root/) addon to create as many different blogs per store as possible. These blogs would all need a different URL, but this could be done using URL's such as:

- en/blog/
- de/blog/
- fr/blog/
- es/blog/

If this sounds like it could work, let me know and I will provide more information.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I feel that the Root addon indeed offers the solution I'm looking for.